# All cards expanding simultaneously rather than singularly when defining with JSON data

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

Is it possible to expand my cards individually rather than as they are doing now, all together?

I have defined an array of JSON data that will be used to fill the details of the cards, but I just cannot seem to get them to expand individually.

**Simple data**

```
export const DATA = [
    {
      name: 'Some name 1',
    },
    {
      name: 'Some name 2',
    }
  ];
```

**.ts file**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  data;
  expanded = [];

  constructor(public toast: MatSnackBar) {
    this.data = DATA;
  }    
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="container">
  <mat-card *ngFor="let item of data" #panel [ngClass]="{expanded: expanded[item]}" [class.mat-elevation-z8]="expanded[item]">
    <div class="header">
      Some content here
      <div class="toggle">
      <button mat-icon-button>
        <mat-icon *ngIf="!expanded[item]" (click)="expanded[panel]=!expanded[item]">
          edit
        </mat-icon>
        <mat-icon *ngIf="expanded[item]" (click)="expanded[item]=!expanded[item]">cancel</mat-icon>
      </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="body" *ngIf="expanded[item]">
      Some content here
    </div>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

[Here is my stackblitz for you to play with](https://stackblitz.com/edit/expand-from-json-singularly)

**Edit:**
My 'logic' above comes from seeing something similarly implemented like this:

```
<mat-card #panel *ngFor="let x of [1,2,3]" [ngClass]="{expanded: thisExpands[x]}">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="toggle">
        <button 
            mat-flat-button 
            (click)="thisExpands[x]=!thisExpands[x]"
...
```

However these cards are generated from a much more simple array of data.

Comment: What is logic to toggle the Expand the card --> you can do this with `let i = index` also

Comment: @PrashantPimpale - I'm not sure how you mean :-/

Comment: If you are using ngClass dynamically then assign that class for particular item from the list

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I'm still not following how you mean. Could you post an example as an answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `index` to access the particular item in the `forLoop`:

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index">

</mat-card>
```

Your HTML Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <mat-card *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index" #panel [ngClass]="{expanded: expanded[i]}" [class.mat-elevation-z8]="expanded[i]">
        <div class="header">
            Some content here
            <div class="toggle">
                <button mat-icon-button>
        <mat-icon *ngIf="!expanded[i]" (click)="expanded[i]=!expanded[i]">
          edit
        </mat-icon>
        <mat-icon *ngIf="expanded[i]" (click)="expanded[i]=!expanded[i]">cancel</mat-icon>
      </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="body" *ngIf="expanded[item]">
      Some content here
    </div>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/expand-from-json-singularly-wgvgn2)

Comment: Ah! I couldn't get my head around adding `let i = index` along side the `let item of data`. Apologies for my slowness this Monday morning! Thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
  <mat-card *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index" #panel [ngClass]="{expanded: expanded[i]}" [class.mat-elevation-z8]="expanded[i]">
    <div class="header">
      Some content here
      <div class="toggle">
      <button mat-icon-button>
        <mat-icon *ngIf="!expanded[i]" (click)="expanded[i]=!expanded[i]">
          edit
        </mat-icon>
        <mat-icon *ngIf="expanded[i]" (click)="expanded[i]=!expanded[i]">cancel</mat-icon>
      </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="body" *ngIf="expanded[i]">
      Some content here
    </div>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

Try this one. Use `index` instead of item.